# Seeking Help in using SOAP in PHP

Tags: php, soap

I work in PHP, but never worked with things like SOAP. But today my managaer told me to fetch request from following SOAP request.
As I don't know what is SOAP and what it's used for and even how to use it in my page.
Can someone please tell me how can I make request a request from this sample request?
Thanks.
I tried searching google, but no relevant results were found.

```
POST /TestService/Service.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: 123.12.12.123
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://abc.com/Mobile"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <Mobile xmlns="http://abc.com/">
      <str>string</str>
    </Mobile>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

**length** and **string** are placeholders.

Comment: Questions containing 'Urgent!!!!!One!!11', PLZ GIMME TEH CODEZ ASAP and alike are considered non-constructive on StackOverflow.

Comment: That's funny. I searched Google and this was my first result: http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getlastresponse.php

Comment: SOAP info in general: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a very useful library, go to this page and download it:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoap/files/

Here's one of the examples provided by the developers:

```
require_once('lib/nusoap.php');
$proxyhost = isset($_POST['proxyhost']) ? $_POST['proxyhost'] : '';
$proxyport = isset($_POST['proxyport']) ? $_POST['proxyport'] : '';
$proxyusername = isset($_POST['proxyusername']) ? $_POST['proxyusername'] : '';
$proxypassword = isset($_POST['proxypassword']) ? $_POST['proxypassword'] : '';
$client = new soapclient('http://www.xignite.com/xquotes.asmx?WSDL', true,
                        $proxyhost, $proxyport, $proxyusername, $proxypassword);
$err = $client->getError();
if ($err) {
    echo '<h2>Constructor error</h2><pre>' . $err . '</pre>';
}
// Doc/lit parameters get wrapped
$param = array('Symbol' => 'IBM');
$result = $client->call('GetQuickQuotes', array('parameters' => $param), '', '', false, true);
// Check for a fault
if ($client->fault) {
    echo '<h2>Fault</h2><pre>';
    print_r($result);
    echo '</pre>';
} else {
    // Check for errors
    $err = $client->getError();
    if ($err) {
        // Display the error
        echo '<h2>Error</h2><pre>' . $err . '</pre>';
    } else {
        // Display the result
        echo '<h2>Result</h2><pre>';
        print_r($result);
        echo '</pre>';
    }
}
echo '<h2>Request</h2><pre>' . htmlspecialchars($client->request, ENT_QUOTES) . '</pre>';
echo '<h2>Response</h2><pre>' . htmlspecialchars($client->response, ENT_QUOTES) . '</pre>';
echo '<h2>Debug</h2><pre>' . htmlspecialchars($client->debug_str, ENT_QUOTES) . '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 1):

This is SOAP http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP

This is SOAP with PHP http://php.net/manual/de/book.soap.php

These links come up first on Google. Must be very hard to miss them.